# Is that possible to have account using more than one login options?

Tags: support

If you login for first time, you should see alternative options for login instead registering. Is that possible that all of alternatives (OpenID, Facebook, etc) synched to one account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Go to [your profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/147459/aryo-adhi-wibisono-legopermono) and click *My Logins*.

[image]

From there you can add a remove OpenIDs you can login with.

[image]

As far as I know you can have as many logins as you want.